# Number Theory, Proving Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, group-isomorphism

I've been trying to find an answer for this problem. All I know at the moment is that I have to use the third isomorphism theorem. Could someone help me out?

Problem:

Let $m, n$ be positive integers such that $n | m$. Prove that
$n \mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z} ≃ \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{m}{n}}$.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What is the statemant of your "third isomorphism theorem"? This can vary for each textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m=dn$ and consider the following commutative diagram with exact rows:$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\{0\}@>>>d\Bbb Z@>>>\Bbb Z@>>>\Bbb Z/d\Bbb Z@>>>\{0\}\\
@.@V\sim VV@V\sim VV@VVV\\
\{0\}@>>>m\Bbb Z@>>>n\Bbb Z@>>>n\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z@>>>\{0\}\\
\end{CD}
where the left-handed vertical homomorphisms are the multiplication by $n$.
A diagram chasing show that the right-handed vertical homomorphism is an isomorphism as well.